# Javascript/CSS: Conditional highlighting tiles Mah Jongg

Tags: javascript, css

I'm designing a Mah jongg style solitaire game. I'm running into 2 problems:

1. Conditional tile selection. The tiles available (to play) will have a shadow applied when the cursor hovers over them. Tiles are selectable if there is no tile to the right OR the left of the tile. I'm hoping to solve this problem using the application and removal of classes ('selectableTile'). The issue is I have no idea how to get the tiles to "sense" whether a tile is to the right and/or left making it available (Right now they all highlight). In the example below 1,4,7 and 3,6,9 tiles would be available to play. If 9 was matched/disappeared, that would make 8 available to play. Any suggestions as to what to look into? I've explored nextsibling but that seems to only look at the NEXT sibling not the previous ones too? Could this be done with just CSS?
2. Layering tiles (piggybacks off first question). The game has 3-4 layers with each subsequent layer being smaller than the last. My plan was just to center everything using flexbox but would that affect selectable tiles depending on the above solution

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #1d9325 0%,#17752d 57%,#013a01 100%);
}

.bottomLayer{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    border:solid purple 2px;
}

.row{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  
}
.tile{
    height:5.75rem;
    width: 4.5rem;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: solid rgb(59, 59, 59) .2px;
}

.selectableTile:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="bottomLayer">
     <div class="row 1">
       <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">1</div>
       <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">2</div>
       <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">3</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row 2">
       <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">4</div>
       <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">5</div>
       <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row 3">
        <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">7</div>
        <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">8</div>
        <div class="tile one selectableTile" id="gameTile">9</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I would use nested arrays to map things out and do the logic portion. Another option would be to use a unique id prop, like the number of the tile. If they are integer values, you could use conditionals to check if the tile number is equal to the current hover id +/- 1; if greater than the id, then highlight the right shadow, etc..